# IBM Cloudant database access problems from dashboard.html

Tags: nginx, haproxy, cloudant

I have four single node installs for IBM Cloudant. All IBM Cloudant instances are installed on RHEL 6.5. Three of the four installs are working just fine. On the fourth, I am having issues with dashboard.html, haproxy, and connecting to databases.  The following are the details from my debugging effort:

1. I used the same install instructions on all 4 machines.
2. I also verified that all RPMS are at same levels.
3. I made sure /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf, and /etc/sysconfig/network are all set correctly.
4. I disabled iptables for some of my tests, with not luck.

haproxy is set to run on port 10080
nginx is set to run on 5657

**from the end of a weatherreport run.**
['cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com'] [warning] Cluster member cloudant@localhost is not connected to this node. Please check whether it is down.

**From haproxy.log**  500's for all of my database from dashboard.html
Mar  2 12:41:38 localhost.localdomain haproxy[26792]: 9.72.190.182:49510 [02/Mar/2016:12:41:38.166] dbfarm dbfarm/prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com 181/0/0/2/183 500 312 - - ---- 5/5/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /stats HTTP/1.1"
Mar  2 12:41:38 localhost.localdomain haproxy[26792]: 9.72.190.182:49516 [02/Mar/2016:12:41:34.963] dbfarm dbfarm/prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com 3417/0/0/2/3419 500 312 - - ---- 5/5/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /_replicator HTTP/1.1"
Mar  2 12:41:38 localhost.localdomain haproxy[26792]: 9.72.190.182:49517 [02/Mar/2016:12:41:34.964] dbfarm dbfarm/prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com 3425/0/0/3/3428 500 312 - - ---- 5/5/1/2/0 0/0 "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1"
Mar  2 12:41:38 localhost.localdomain haproxy[26792]: 9.72.190.182:49518 [02/Mar/2016:12:41:34.968] dbfarm dbfarm/prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com 3422/0/0/3/3425 500 312 - - ---- 5/5/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /ray HTTP/1.1"
Mar  2 12:41:38 localhost.localdomain haproxy[26792]: 9.72.190.182:49515 [02/Mar/2016:12:41:34.925] dbfarm dbfarm/prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com 3726/0/0/2/3728 500 312 - - ---- 5/5/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /test2 HTTP/1.1"

**from cloudant.log**
2016-03-02 12:55:52.245 [error] cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com <0.10284.0> Missing IOQ stats db: 
2016-03-02 12:56:04.066 [error] cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com <0.10127.0> httpd 500 error response:
 {"error":"nodedown","reason":"progress not possible"}

**from firebug...**
I see 500's when attempting to access all db's
Example:  http://prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com:10080/test2"

I have performed a clean install of IBM Cloudant twice and the issue persists.

Comment: also simply using wget to hit the database's.  produces same 500 errors.

Answer (score 1):

solved, the DELETE command worked, then I just needed to rerun "configure.sh -D"  Which deleted all of the db's and recreated them.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the system has had multiple node names over its lifetime, i.e. previously it was brought up with the node name `cloudant@localhost` and now it has the node name `cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com`. Any databases created when the node name was `cloudant@localhost` will therefore be unavailable now.

What does the output of `curl -X GET http://prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com:10080/_membership` look like?

Comment: That is the odd thing, I wiped the system clean of all cloudant artifacts when I did the scratch installs.  It is as if, there is some sort of hidden file that I may have missed.  All of the files that I know about compare the same to a working system.  I compared the entire cloudant install tree with a working system.  I am thinking it coula also be some sort of OS network config.

Comment: [ashworth@us.ibm.com@prdpcrdlp01 ~]> curl -U admin:admin -X GET http://prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com:10080/_membership
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
[ashworth@us.ibm.com@prdpcrdlp01 ~]>

Comment: [ashworth@us.ibm.com@prdpcrdlp01 ~]> curl -U admin:admin -X GET http://admin:admin@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com:10080/_membership
{"all_nodes":["cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com"],"cluster_nodes":["cloudant@localhost","cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com"]}
[ashworth@us.ibm.com@prdpcrdlp01 ~]>

Comment: [ashworth@us.ibm.com@prdpcrdacs01 ~]> curl -U admin:admin -X GET http://admin:cldadm1n@prdpcrdacs01.w3-969.ibm.com:81/_membership
{"all_nodes":["cloudant@prdpcrdacs01.w3-969.ibm.com"],"cluster_nodes":["cloudant@prdpcrdacs01.w3-969.ibm.com"]}

Comment: I am trying to find a way to remove the "cloudant@localhost" node.  Have not found any docs on this yet.  Although I did see some info in couchdb docs, but I haven ot been able to translate to cloudant.

Comment: was able to remove node using this...  
'curl -X DELETE http://admin:admin@localhost:5986/nodes/cloudant@localhost?rev="1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"'

Comment: and now I see these in my log...
2016-03-03 09:55:52.582 [error] cloudant@prdpcrdlp01.w3-969.ibm.com <0.733.0> req_err(2300864081) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
    [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L177">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L188">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L188">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L143">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L79">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>,